# Read data in a proper way

Tags: cuda

I have a cpp file where I am creating an image and store the data to myOutput pointer:

```
int Rows = 80;
int Cols = 64;

for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++ ){

   for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ )
    {

X = 1.0f * ((float) i - (float) Rows / 2) / (float) Rows;
Y = 2.0f * ((float) j - (float) Cols / 2) / (float) Cols;
.....
myOutput->Re = cosf( ......);
myOutput->Im = sinf(.......);

++myOutput;

    }
}
```

Then , in cuda I am reading like:

```
int bx = blockIdx.x , by = blockIdx.y;
int tx = threadIdx.x , ty = threadIdx.y;

int RowIdx = ty + by * TILE_WIDTH;
int ColIdx = tx + bx * TILE_WIDTH;


Index = RowIdx * Cols + ColIdx;

//copy input data to shared memory
myshared[ty+1][tx+1] = *( devInputArray + Index );
```

(So , the myOutput generated from cpp is loaded in devInputArray).

Now , I want to process many images simultaneously.

So, in cpp ,the following additions must be made (for 2 images for example) :

```
int ImagesNb = 2;

for ( ImagesIdx = 0; ImagesIdx < ImagesNb; ImagesIdx++ ){
   for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++ ){

       for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++ )
        {

 X = (ImagesIdx + 1) * 1.0f * ((float) i - (float) Rows / 2) / (float) Rows;
 Y = (ImagesIdx + 1) * 2.0f * ((float) j - (float) Cols / 2) / (float) Cols;
...
```

But , now I am not sure how to read the data from cuda.

I don't know how to take into account the number of images.

Before , I had a pointer which contained  data (80 x 64) .

Now , it still contains the same dimension of every image but with more data.

I must change this:

```
Index = RowIdx * Cols + ColIdx;

//copy input data to shared memory
myshared[ty+1][tx+1] = *( devInputArray + Index );
```

but I can't figure how!

I hope it is clear!

**UPDATED**

I am trying something like this:

```
 int bx = blockIdx.x , by = blockIdx.y ,  bz = blockIdx.z;
 int tx = threadIdx.x , ty = threadIdx.y , tz = threadIdx.z;

 int RowIdx = ty + by * TILE_WIDTH;
 int ColIdx = tx + bx * TILE_WIDTH;
 int ImagesIdx = tz + bz * blockDim.z;

 Index = RowIdx * Cols + ColIdx + Rows * Cols * ImagesIdx
```

and :

```
dim3 dimGrid( ImagesNb * (Cols / TILE_WIDTH)  , ImagesNb * (Rows / TILE_WIDTH) , ImagesNb);
dim3 dimBlock( TILE_WIDTH , TILE_WIDTH , 2);
```

but if I try for 2 images I am not getting right results..

Comment: I think the way to go is to process multiple images per block. The ideal case would be to process all the images concurrently, but obviously due to the limited size of shared memory you face an upper limit for the number of images that you can load and process per block. According to the size of shared memory available per thread block, you may find this maximum possible number of images. You probably need to pad the input data to adjust the size as well. Details depend on the operations you perform on the shared memory data.

Comment: @ramino:Hello , I updated if you want to check ,thanks

Comment: I don't see why you have considered both grid and block dimensions to be 3. If you find it easier to work with higher dimensional blocks, you can consider a 2D grid of 3D blocks. Then check if you can fit 2 images (or more) in one block. What can possibly cause the problem, is the way you use shared memory. As the name implies, it is shared, therefore you have to ensure each image is accessing the right portion of data from shared memory and does not overwrite data of another image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for using a number of images you must add an extra dimension to shared variable in order to hold the number of images.